# Extract a substring using command line utilities

Tags: command-line, substring

I have a text file including lines in the form of:

```
(term1 x:a y:b (term2 z:c k:a))
```

I want to extract only terms from this line using command line utilities such as awk, grep, sed. i.e I want the result to be:

```
term1 
term2
```

I have formed a regex matching the rest but the terms, but could not find a way to negate it.

```
(\()|( \()|( (.*?) \()|( (.*?)\)+)
```

How can I form a command extracting the every substring after '(' and before ' '?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed "s/(\([^ (]*\)[^(]*/\1\n/g"
```

For example:

```
$ echo "(term1 x:a y:b (term2 (term3)  z:c k:a) x (termX a:b ) )" | sed "s/(\([^ )]*\)[^(]*/\1\n/g"
term1
term2
term3
termX
```